# Twitch if user type more than 10 emotes

Tags: javascript, twitch

I'm writing a Twitch bot using TMI.js and I want it so if you type more than 10 emotes in chat then it will respond with a message. On TMIjs website it says `'emotes': { '25': [ '0-4'] },` under `message` in `Events`. I currently have

```
if (userstate.emotes > "10") {
    client.say("Channel", "More than 10");
}
```

but this says "More than 10" no matter how many emotes are used - however it only does it with emotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with TMI.js, but I think that

```
userstate.emotes > "10"
```

should be

```
userstate.emotes > 10
```

If `10` is in quotes, it will be treated as a string.

Comment: Actually, if `userstate.emotes` is a number, JavaScript will cast `"10"` to a number.  See https://jsfiddle.net/ho2mah9s/.  So it's a good suggestion but unlikely to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it to show once when the user has written more than 10 emotes, then you could probably do something like

```
if (parseInt(userstate.emotes) === 11) {
    client.say("Channel", "More than 10");
}
```

Then you will fire a message when the user types the 11th emote.

but I'm not entirely sure what functionality you're trying to accomplish, or how TMI.js works.

Comment: Didn't work - the message never fired no matter how many emotes I done.